# MySQL if-statment use with where clause

Tags: mysql

How to add an additional WHERE clause to a query. Having this query:

```
SELECT round(Sum(Zarada), 2) AS Zarada, 
       cms_cart_customers.Firstname,
       cms_cart_wallet.WalletType as WW ,
       cms_cart_customers.Lastname, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(`cms_cart_customers`.`d_ins`, " %d.%m.%Y") AS Datum_formatiran 
  FROM (cms_cart_customers) 
  LEFT JOIN cms_cart_wallet
    ON cms_cart_wallet.IdBuyer =cms_cart_customers.Id 
  WHERE `cms_cart_customers`.`IDReferral` = '199' AND
        if(ww = 7) THEN ' cms_cart_wallet.WalletType =7' END IF 
  GROUP BY cms_cart_customers.Id
```

If Selected cms_cart_wallet.WalletType as Ww Then add new extra clause WHERE cms_cart_wallet.WalletType is 7 . Is possible to do that in this way???

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at `WHERE cms_cart_customers.IDReferral = '199' or (ww = 7 and cms_cart_wallet.WalletType =7)`

Comment: i am trying to achive if SELECTED WalletType == 7 ADD Extra clause  WHERE cms_cart_wallet.WalletType =7

Comment: what you will achieve with this...

Comment: I have left Join with tables. I wanna results from two tables, still if connection do not exist, but if exists add clouse where walletType is 7, but still show value wich dont have par from second table i mean (walletType )

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding one more clause in left join on condition like below.

```
SELECT round(Sum(Zarada), 2) AS Zarada, cms_cart_customers.Firstname,cms_cart_wallet.WalletType as WW ,cms_cart_customers.Lastname, FROM_UNIXTIME(cms_cart_customers.d_ins, " %d.%m.%Y") AS Datum_formatiran FROM (cms_cart_customers) LEFT JOIN cms_cart_wallet ON cms_cart_wallet.IdBuyer =cms_cart_customers.Id and cms_cart_wallet.WalletType =7 WHERE cms_cart_customers.IDReferral = '199'  GROUP BY cms_cart_customers.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add that in where clause directly without using any alias.

SELECT round(Sum(Zarada), 2) AS Zarada, 
cms_cart_customers.Firstname,cms_cart_wallet.WalletType as WW ,
cms_cart_customers.Lastname, FROM_UNIXTIME(cms_cart_customers.d_ins, " %d.%m.%Y") AS Datum_formatiran
 FROM (cms_cart_customers)
 LEFT JOIN cms_cart_wallet ON cms_cart_wallet.IdBuyer =cms_cart_customers.Id 
WHERE cms_cart_customers.IDReferral = '199' and cms_cart_wallet.WalletType =7  GROUP BY cms_cart_customers.Id

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if` for this.  Simple conditional logic suffices:

```
  WHERE cms_cart_customers.IDReferral = '199' AND
        (ww <> 7 or cms_cart_wallet.WalletType = 7)
```

To handle `NULL` values:

```
  WHERE cms_cart_customers.IDReferral = '199' AND
        (COALESCE(ww, 0) <> 7 or cms_cart_wallet.WalletType = 7)
```